# Pyomo visualizing data with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyomo

I've solved a model and trying to visualize the results by using matplolib.

This model can run properly. I am trying to fix the variables and re-solve this model and output three different bar charts in order to compare it with others.
But when I applied matplotlib to draw the bar chart, only the last one was drawn (cost 20171.984)

How to output three different bar charts?

what I have done so far is like that:

```
for s in [800, 1000, 1200]:
    instance.demand = s
    opt = SolverFactory('Ipopt')
    results = opt.solve(instance)
    print('Cost: ', value(instance.cost))

# cost printed
Cost:  13139.706753161874
Cost:  16460.857089915964
Cost:  20171.984469196814

# Matplotlib
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
x = [0.1]
plt.bar(x, value(instance.cost), alpha=0.7, width=0.015).........Code omitted in this part
```

Could you help me with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
costs = []
for s in [800, 1000, 1200]:
    instance.demand = s
    opt = SolverFactory('Ipopt')
    results = opt.solve(instance)
    print('Cost: ', value(instance.cost))
    costs.append(value(instance.cost))
```

You then have the list `costs` which you can plot as shown in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

3 costs, 1 chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

xlabels = ["bar1","bar2", "bar3"]
costs = [13139, 16460, 33333]

bar = plt.bar(xlabels, costs, width=0.8, color=['blue', 'red', 'green'])
plt.xticks(range(len(xlabels)), xlabels)

plt.ylabel("Costs")
plt.xlabel("X label")
plt.legend((bar[0], bar[1], bar[2]), xlabels, loc="upper right")
plt.title("My chart")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry sir, the cost was calculated from my instance. The value of cost is unknown, so i need to use something like `plt.bar(x, value(instance.cost)` to visualize the result. Could you help me with it? I want to output three bar charts from my model which could compare with others to show the sensitivity.